# sum of rank of matrices is equal to no of columns and rank of product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

A and I are two $n \times n$ matrices.
Prove that $ R(A) + R(I-A) = n + R(A - A^2 $).

I used the inequality $R(A(I-A)) \geq R(A) + R(I-A) - n$

So  $ R(A^2-A)) + n \geq R(A) + R(I-A)$

How to prove the equality condition?

Comment: Note that $I$ is not just any matrix, it is the identity matrix. You could prove this equality by showing that $\ker(A-A^2)=\ker A(I-A)=\ker A\oplus \ker (I-A)$ and then using the rank-nullity theorem.